# Casting byte to DateTime causing error C#

Tags: c#, datetime, byte

When trying to perform the following cast

```
DateTime issueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(binfile.ReadByte());
```

(reading .dat files by the way) I get a run time error saying, "Invalid cast from byte to DateTime"

Not sure why I am getting this error, nor how to fix it.

When I use the same approach with a string it works fine,

```
string firstName = Convert.ToString(binfile.ReadByte());
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What time is it? I don't know. 0xFD maybe? A byte can only hold 8 bits, that's 256 different values. How do you think you can get a `DateTime` out of it?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to read? ".dat" does not say anything at all. Is it a binary format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert the byte to DateTime. If the dt value is stored as ticks then the code should be

```
DateTime issueDate = new DateTime(binfile.ReadInt64());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's hardly surprising. How is the .Net framework supposed to cast a byte to DateTime?

The conversion to string works: a byte can be represented as a string, as almost every class/struct in the framework.

But a byte is a byte. It's not a datetime.

What you should be doing is, if I guess correctly, reading the text contained in the file "as text", isolate the part that represents a valid DateTime string, and then convert it. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

binfile.ReadByte() unsigned byte of type Int32. If you try to convert this to `DateTime` definitely it will fail. You should be reading a complete string and then type casting it to `DateTime`

Comment: you can't cast a string to a DateTime. You can parse the string and get a DateTime value as the result

Answer (score 0):

May be that's because you read just one byte from stream and sizeof(DateTime) is 8 bytes. What value gets Convert.ToString(binfile.ReadByte()) ? Is it right value?

Answer (score 0):

How would you like it to work?  There are 256 possible values for a byte; without more information, there's no meaningful conversion: which set of 256 or fewer DateTime values would you like to associate with the integers from 0 to 255?

If you have an answer to that question, you can implement the conversion yourself with little trouble.

Answer (score 0):

can use BitConverter to for converting int64 (that is long) and after that take datetime from long with DateTime.FromBinary

```
            long utcMD = BitConverter.ToInt64(xBankPacketStructureParser.baMessageDate, 0);
            xBankPacket.xMessageDateTime = DateTime.FromBinary(utcMD);
```